# Naive implementation of Rainbow Table and/or Hellman's trade-off

Tags: hash, rainbow-table

This question is the same one I asked [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/naive-implementation-of-rainbow-table-and-or-hellmans-trade-off). Since I haven't got any response or even a comment I will post it here as well.

Is there any naive implementation of [Hellman's cryptanalytic time memory tradeoff](http://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc609.122/doc/36.pdf) in C and/or a naive implementation of [Oechslin's rainbow table algorithm](http://pages.csam.montclair.edu/~perrieror/projects/CMPT495-clustering.and.security/resources/philippe.oechslin-making.a.faster.cryptanalytical.time.memory.trade.off.pdf) in C as well?

I have seen some implementations of rainbow table but they are always focused on being fast through the usage of assembly-level operations or being designed to work on a specific platform such as CUDA or FPGAs.

Comment: The reason you see implementations in CUDA or FPGAs is because the algorithms can be highly optimized for speed and efficiency for real world applications.  You could try looking for UPC implementations, but initial searches for me turned up nothing.

Comment: @raz Yes, I have researched for some time now, still nothing. My hope is that someone have this code but haven't shared with the world yet.

Comment: I found some straight forward implementations in C [on github](https://github.com/search?l=C&q=rainbowtable&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) but no luck with Hellman`s table

Comment: why do you need it in C?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [the article](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/crypto-sam-sebe-rainbowproject-4298) - it's about naive implementation of Rainbow Tables for cracking MD5 hash function. It also has sources attached to the article. The **main drawback - it's in Russian**, but [Yandex.Translate](https://translate.yandex.ru) or Google Translate can easily cope with it.